# Unable to compile for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile

```
public class ForwardLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstNumber = 5;
        int lastNumber = 45;
        int hopValue =  5;

        for(firstNumber; firstNumber <= lastNumber; firstNumber = firstNumber + hopValue) {
            System.out.print(firstNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

But I end up getting an error at line 9, stating that it's not a statement.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The initialization in the `for` loop statement must be a valid statement. `firstNumber` is not a valid statement. In your case, you can just have the initialization as an empty statement because you already assigned the initial value before:

```
for (; firstNumber <= lastNumber; firstNumber = firstNumber + hopValue) {
    System.out.print(firstNumber);
}
```

Or you can move the declaration inside the `for` loop but this will limit its scope to only the loop:

```
// You can also use the += operator
for (int firstNumber = 5; firstNumber <= lastNumber; firstNumber += hopValue) {
    System.out.print(firstNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of for loop

```
for(initialization; condition; iteration)
{
    //statements
}
```

As you see in your code you are not initialized `firstNumber` so write code in proper syntax as follows:

```
for(firstNumber=5; firstNumber <= lastNumber; firstNumber = firstNumber + hopValue)
{
      System.out.print(firstNumber );
}
```

Initialize the firstNumber in for loop only or if you initialize the variable before for loop then keep initialization blank so that's look like follows:

```
for( ;condition; iteration)
{
    // statements
}
```